# SQL Server: "This filegroup cannot be used as a backup destination" error when attempting restore

Tags: sql, sql-server

When running a command like the following:

```
"RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='\\\\server\\folder\\DummyDB.bak'"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Backup destination "\\server" supports a FILESTREAM filegroup. This filegroup cannot be used as a backup destination. Rerun the BACKUP statement with a valid backup destination.
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.
```

Unless someone comes up with a better idea, it seems that the drive from which restore is being attempted must not contain any database file contained in a filegroup. Is that the case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you are getting an error message I would assume that is the case.

Comment: do you get the error when your attempting a restore?, or when your attempting the list the files in the backup? (i.e. your first command)

Comment: Nick - when attempting a restore, see above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has been noted as a bug by Microsoft.  It is scheduled to be fixed in the future.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/591263/unable-to-perform-backups-to-server-that-has-network-share-filestream-hdr